Cannot use external function inside page.evaluate()
I am scraping dynamic website with puppeteer. My goal is to be able to create as much generic scraping logic as possible, which will also remove a lot of boilerplate code. So for that reason, I created external function that scrapes the data, given certain parameters. The problem was that when I tried to use that function inside page.evaluate() puppeteer method, I ran into a ReferenceError that this function was not defined.
Did some research and the page.exposeFunction() & page.addScriptTag() came out as a possible solutions. However when I tried to use them inside my scraper, addScriptTag() wasn't working and exposeFunction() didn't give me the ability to access DOM elements inside the exposed function. I understood that exposeFunction() is being executed inside Node.js, while addScriptTag() - in the browser, but I don't know how to proceed further with that information and if it is even valuable for my case.
Here is my scraper:
import { Browser } from "puppeteer";

import { dataMapper } from "../../utils/api/functions/data-mapper.js";

export const mainCategoryScraper = async (browser: Browser) => {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.setUserAgent(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
  );

  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on("request", (req) => {
    if (
      req.resourceType() === "stylesheet" ||
      req.resourceType() === "font" ||
      req.resourceType() === "image"
    ) {
      req.abort();
    } else {
      req.continue();
    }
  });

  await page.goto("https://www.ozone.bg/pazeli-2d-3d/nastolni-igri", {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
  });

  /**
   * Function will execute in Node.js
   */
  // await page.exposeFunction('dataMapper', dataMapper);

  /**
   * The way of passing DOM elements to the function, because like that the function executes in the browser
   */
  // await page.addScriptTag({ content: `${dataMapper}` });

  const data = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const contentContainer = document.querySelector(".col-main") as HTMLDivElement;

    const carousels = Array.from(
      contentContainer.querySelectorAll(".owl-item") as NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement>
    );

    const carouselsData = await dataMapper<HTMLDivElement>(carousels, ".title", "img", "a");

    return {
      carouselsData,
    };
  });
  await browser.close();

  return data;
};


And here is the dataMapper function:
import { PossibleTags } from "../typescript/types.js";

export const dataMapper = function <T extends HTMLDivElement>(items: Array<T>, ...selectors: string[]) {
  let hasTitle = false;

  for (const selector of selectors) {
    if (selector === ".title" || selector === "h3") {
      hasTitle = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  return items.map((item) => {
    const data: PossibleTags = {};

    return selectors.map((selector) => {
        
      const dataProp = item.querySelector(selector);

      switch (selector) {
        case ".title": {
          data["title"] = (dataProp as HTMLSpanElement)?.innerText;
          break;
        }
        case "h3": {
          data["title"] = (dataProp as HTMLHeadingElement)?.innerText;
          break;
        }
        case "h6": {
          data["subTitle"] = (dataProp as HTMLHeadingElement)?.innerText;
          break;
        }
        case "img": {
          if (!hasTitle) {
            data["img"] = (dataProp as HTMLImageElement)?.getAttribute("src") ?? undefined;
            break;
          }

          data["title"] = (dataProp as HTMLImageElement)?.getAttribute("alt") ?? undefined;
          break;
        }
        case "a": {
          data["url"] = (dataProp as HTMLAnchorElement)?.getAttribute("href") ?? undefined;
        }
        default: {
          throw new Error("Such selector is not yet added to the possible selectors");
        }
      }
    });
  });
};

When I use the page.exposeFunction('dataMapper', dataMapper);, it tells me that item.querySelector is not a function (inside dataMapper). And with await page.addScriptTag({ content: `${dataMapper}` });, it just throws error later on inside the page.evaluate, that dataMapper is not a function.
Update: when specifying path inside the addScriptTag, it still gives me: Error [ReferenceError]: dataMapper is not defined
*
Just to mention that the mainCategoryScraper * is later on used in scrapersHandler function, which decides what scraper to be executed, based on URL endpoint.

What's your expected output? There's probably a pretty direct approach to getting it--this is a somewhat unusual setup--dataMapper presents as a generic function, yet it's super-hardcoded to specific selectors like .title, so it doesn't seem that obviously reusable. addScriptTag should work though, or use evaluate() to attach the function to the window so future evaluate blocks can access it. async/await is not necessary in your evaluate--the DOM is pretty much all sync.

@ggorlen This will scrape the items, the slider of the page and the widgetBoxes from certain landing page

As discussed in my comment, the approach here seems rather convoluted. I'd caution against premature abstractions.
In general, once you need to add multiple conditions (switch and if) where there weren't any before, you may be headed down the wrong path. These increase the cognitive complexity of the code. Complexity in a function can be acceptable if it reduces complexity for the caller, but if the contract for the function isn't clear, then the abstraction may leak problems back to the caller.
Packing all of the logic into your dataMapper function breaches the single responsibility principle and makes it unmaintainable, because you'll need to keep burdening it further with additional types of structures. The control flow within the function is already difficult to grasp and can't be extended in any sensible way. The caller should be responsible for explicitly encoding the structure to be scraped, rather than trying to write an all-in-one function that can't sensibly be written for these structures.
Another rule of thumb: if the factoring is difficult, then just keep the repetition. Or take a step back and try to write a different abstraction, either at a higher or lower level than the first attempt.
In this case, you might write a couple of higher-level abstractions $$evalMap and $text, which let you write your data mappers more cleanly. These abstractions just clear some of the syntax out of the way, but don't attempt to generalize scraping different structures with conditions.
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.7.1

const url = "https://www.ozone.bg/pazeli-2d-3d/nastolni-igri";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  const blockedResources = [
    "image",
    "fetch",
    "other",
    "ping",
    "stylesheet",
    "xhr",
  ];
  page.on("request", req => {
    if (
      !req.url().startsWith("https://www.ozone.bg") ||
      blockedResources.includes(req.resourceType())
    ) {
      req.abort();
    } else {
      req.continue();
    }
  });
  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(
    "window.$text = (el, s) => el.querySelector(s)?.textContent.trim();"
  );
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

  const $$evalMap = async (sel, mapFn) => {
    await page.waitForSelector(sel);
    return page.$$eval(
      sel,
      (els, mapFn) => els.map(new Function(`return ${mapFn}`)()),
      mapFn.toString()
    );
  };

  const carouselData = await $$evalMap(".owl-item", el => ({
    title: $text(el, ".title"),
    img: el.querySelector("img").src,
    url: el.querySelector("a").href,
  }));

  const widgetData = await $$evalMap(".widget-box", el => ({
    title: el.querySelector("img").alt,
    img: el.querySelector("img").src,
    url: el.querySelector("a").href,
  }));

  const sliderData = await $$evalMap(
    ".item.slick-slide",
    el => ({
      title: $text(el, "h3"),
      subTitle: $text(el, "h6"),
      img: el.querySelector("img").src,
      url: el.querySelector("a").href,
    })
  );

  console.log(carouselData);
  console.log(widgetData);
  console.log(sliderData);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

If TypeScript types are getting in the way, consider moving the querySelectors out to similar helper functions as was done with $text. The $$evalMap calls can also be moved out to individual functions for each section (scrapeCarouselData, scrapeWidgetData, scrapeSliderData, etc). Doing so would require $$evalMap to accept a page parameter, but if you're breaking out functions, it may not be necessary anyway since the complexity is hidden--plain $$eval seems perfectly acceptable too, especially if there are only three.
Breaking up this main IIFE into sub-functions would be straightforward:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const $$evalMap = async (page, sel, mapFn) => {
  await page.waitForSelector(sel);
  return page.$$eval(
    sel,
    (els, mapFn) => els.map(new Function(`return ${mapFn}`)()),
    mapFn.toString()
  );
};

const scrapeCarouselData = page =>
  $$evalMap(page, ".owl-item", el => ({
    title: $text(el, ".title"),
    img: el.querySelector("img").src,
    url: el.querySelector("a").href,
  }));

const scrapeWidgetData = page =>
  $$evalMap(page, ".widget-box", el => ({
    title: el.querySelector("img").alt,
    img: el.querySelector("img").src,
    url: el.querySelector("a").href,
  }));

const scrapeSliderData = page =>
  $$evalMap(page, ".item.slick-slide", el => ({
    title: $text(el, "h3"),
    subTitle: $text(el, "h6"),
    img: el.querySelector("img").src,
    url: el.querySelector("a").href,
  }));

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  // ... same optimization code,  could be moved out to a set up func
  const url = "https://www.ozone.bg/pazeli-2d-3d/nastolni-igri";
  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(
    "window.$text = (el, s) => el.querySelector(s)?.textContent.trim();"
  );
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  console.log(await scrapeCarouselData(page));
  console.log(await scrapeWidgetData(page));
  console.log(await scrapeSliderData(page));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

$$evalMap is a little ugly but can be moved out to an imported utility function that lives in another file. The scrapers rely on $text existing, so some shared/global setup could be the place for this to live, potentially along with the optimization code in the first snippet.
Now the main code is quite clean, and each scraping function is easy to maintain.
Writing similar scraping functions would follow the established pattern. If a particular section doesn't adhere well to the $$evalMap paradigm, no problem--it should use its own bespoke logic rather than trying to cram it into one of the existing functions with a condition.
Summary and further remarks:

Avoid premature abstractions.
When factoring, stop if you're introducing multiple conditions where there weren't any before. switch/case/break is particularly nasty. If your abstractions are more verbose and hard to understand than the original repeated code, don't do them, or try to find a different abstraction.
When factoring, write it the verbose way first, then try to abstract away the similarities (but a bit of repetition is acceptable--be honest about what's easier to read and maintain).
as is discouraged in TS. Use it as little as possible in favor of variable types.
Use $$eval all the time. It's the most generally useful scraping function in Puppeteer, avoiding an ugly Array.from(document.querySelectorAll) or element handles. If Puppeteer's locators API matures in the future, $$eval may be supplanted, but for now it's the way to go.
?? undefined is unnecessary. If the left hand chained operator ?. fails, the expression evaluates to undefined anyway, so undefined ?? undefined is pointless.
Generally speaking, you don't need addScriptTag or exposeFunction. If you're writing $text-like abstractions often, you can jQuery or something like that to simplify querying.
In web scraping, there are no silver bullets for selection, so be very cautious when attempting to generalize--it's not impossible, but requires a good deal of care and case-specific planning.


So you suggest adding the dataMapper to the window object with evaluate and then using it inside the second evaluate, because I am not sure if this gave me access to the querySelector inside dataMapper. addScriptTag didn't work, maybe I did something wrong?: await page.addScriptTag({ path: "build\\utils\\api\\functions\\data-mapper.js" });

Here I have 2 other targets: const slider = Array.from( contentContainer.querySelectorAll(".item.slick-slide") as NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement> ); const widgetBoxes = Array.from( contentContainer.querySelectorAll(".widget-box") as NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement> );  So with $$eval, I will have a lot of repeating code, I think, this is why I created such more generic fn like dataMapper, it is not perfect, but works just fine for that one website, I mean if needed the use cases can just be extended and more logic can be added.

It's hard to make sense of your code there. Can you share these additional websites? As I wrote in my answer, I don't see any motivation for your abstractions yet. The attempted logic with the hardcoded class and tag names, switch and ifs everywhere, injecting script tags, using booleans and hardcoded strings and making multiple CDP calls is verbose and not maintainable. There is certainly a better way, but it depends on the additional requirements, which are not apparent based on the info so far.

.widget-box and .item.slick-slide have totally different content and structure than .owl-item. What data are you trying to extract from these other containers? Writing one function to scrape 3 totally dissimilar things doesn't make sense. There should be 3 separate "data mappers" for those (or just don't use "data mappers" and scrape them directly, as shown in my answer, with 3 different $$evals--there is no common ground so no point in trying to achieve resuability where there is little or none to be had).

I added how I scraped each class previously, so you can see. One url that I am scraping is "https://www.ozone.bg/pazeli-2d-3d/nastolni-igri", and the selectors are simillar for each page, category, only scraping individual item is a bit different. The main reason is that I wanted to avoid uneccesary boilerplate code, i.e., repeating almost the same mapping function for different contexts. So I extracted it into 1 main dataMapper. If you can, open the link that I provided above and see the similarities. Is there better way you could suggest? The type of data is also shown there.

I don't think we're aligned here. I see the page, which I've shown you how to scrape the .owl-items for. You've mentioned two additional categories, but they have totally different structures than the .owl-items, and I mentioned that there's no point in extracting them into one main data mapper since they're so different. There's not much data to pull out of .item.slick-side and .widget-box--no prices, just titles and images. So you can pull those out easily using the same code I've already given you, optionally tossed into a function. Unless I'm missing something.

Here's the general rule of thumb for factoring: write the different functions separately at first, with repetition, then later it'll be apparent how to cleanly abstract/extract/factor, if necessary. If your factoring packs a bunch of conditions, booleans and hardcoded strings in it (which your dataMapper does), then it's probably not a good abstraction. Back up and either try again to do it cleanly, without branches, or live with a little bit of repetition.

So you suggest that I just go with using $$eval for each category? Indeed there is not much data in .item.slick-side and .widget-box, it is more of a practice. If I may ask, when would you suggest creating such general function like dataMapper. How could I avoid that hardcoded data in my dataMapper in this particular case?

Yes, I'd start by taking my $$eval and applying it to each separate structure, rather than trying to jam all of the logic into one function, overloading it and breaching the single responsibility principle. Once you have that, it should be apparent how to combine them into a more general function because the repetition will be visible. If there's not much repetition and you wind up with lots of conditions, then you're trying too hard to create a general function when there isn't the need for it. I'd create a general function when there's an obvious, clean factoring path and pressing need.

It also depends on the final output structure I need to create, although sometimes there are poor decisions in choosing that structure, like missing data and differing keys. Generally, an array of objects should share the same structure and key properties on each object, which this output already doesn't do, which means you'll need conditions later on. Sometimes the data is just like that, but to the extent you can, I'd try to avoid it.

OK, after this post, I think I understand your scenario better and I've updated my answer. Thanks for your patience and let me know what you think.

Thank you so much, @ggorlen! You surely helped me, but the main question still remains. I read you talked about that I don't need addScriptTag or exposeFunction, but potentially if I don't use them, and need one function in more than one place, wouldn't I just end up with repeating code inside each scraper, because my initial problem was that I couldn't use external function into the evaluate with neither of addScriptTag or exposeFunction?

Sorry, I still don't follow the problem exactly. There are some rare use cases for addScriptTag and exposeFunction but I don't see that they're necessary here, although I am using evaluate to add a simple helper to more easily extract text. What's the issue you're struggling with? What do you mean by "each scraper" and which "more than one place" are you referring to? if you're referring to scrapeCarouselData and the other scraping functions in my code, you can export them from a module and use them anywhere. Or you can export the main scraper.

If I move scrapeSliderData into another file and import it into the main scraper, just to learn to avoid repetition in different files, I wasn't able to use it inside the evaluate.

I tried your method, but moved the methods in an external file, and replaced $text(el, "h6") for example , with el.querySelector("h6").textContent.trim() and now get the same error here el.querySelector is not a function

Hmm, not sure what went wrong, but that shouldn't be an error, assuming you refactored correctly and you're running on the same site. Does my code work for you if you copy-paste it verbatim? If so, then I suggest opening a new question and posting your latest code. Tag me and I'll take a look. BTW, el.querySelector("h6").textContent.trim() is not quite right. It should probably be el.querySelector("h6")?.textContent.trim() because there are a lot of missing elements. This is a slightly different error than you stated though, el should definitely not be null.

I copy pasted all your code verbatim and still get the same error Error [TypeError]: el.querySelector is not a function. The only modifications is that I wrapped your code inside function, which I can export to use in different file.

I see the problem, my mistake. I forgot to update scrapeSliderData when refactoring or when pasting to SO. Try again now and let me know if you have any issues running the current code.

Hey @ggorlen, it is working now! Can you just provide me a good post or a quick explanation of how you constructed $$evalMap, because it seems rather confusing. And also about that part page.evaluateOnNewDocument(       "window.$text = (el, s) => el.querySelector(s)?.textContent.trim();"     ); - is this the way to attach methods to the window obj and is it a good practice, because somewhere I read that it is not? Thank you!

Thanks for confirming. When you use $$eval, 99% of the time the only thing you do is call elements.map() and return the result. Also, you generally want to wait for a selector to exist before trying to $$eval it. So all $$evalMap does is wait and bake the mapper in. Unfortunately, you have to serialize a function manually so it's a little ugly, but it's library code that you can bury in a utility.

As for attaching a method to the window, it's the only way to add generally reusable functions in the browser in Puppeteer. Adding a script tag is no different than doing it in an evaluate--either way, you attach something to the window. It's not a good idea if you're developing the site, but if you're scraping, it doesn't make a difference as long as the site you're scraping doesn't rely on that same property name. The odds of the site having $text on their window is practically zero, but you can always use a more obfuscated name or a namespace of your own if you have multiple functions.

You can also write out the querySelectors for text each time if you want, or use jQuery or another library if that makes you more comfortable. I prefer to avoid the dependency and loading time, so I think $text as I showed is a perfectly reasonable macro to install. Ditto for $$evalMap--you don't have to use this shorthand. It's just a convenience, along with $text, not exactly the main points of my post, which are $$eval and abstracting correctly. The other syntactical shorthands are up to you to use or not as you see fit. Multiple approaches are valid.

Thank you so much, @ggorlen! Can you just explain me this part, because it seems quite interesting approach: return page.$$eval(       sel,       (els, mapFn) => els.map(new Function(`return ${mapFn}`)()),       mapFn.toString()     );

What about it don't you understand, in light of what I wrote above? I'm serializing the mapping function, passing it into $$eval and deserializing it in the browser and using it as an argument to els.map().

Well, I don't understand the new Function() and the return as a string + why toString is used after there. Thank you!

Did you read the serialize a function link? Since the code runs in a different process, you need to serialize and deserialize the function when passing it across processes. Usually Puppeteer handles serialization/deserialization, but in this case its built in serializer doesn't work on functions, probably because it's using JSON.stringify. In any case, you don't really need to understand how it works in order to use it, just like a normal Puppeteer library function. You can treat it as a black box that "just works magically".
